# What article in front of "skin"?

Tags: articles

1. Don't get excited every time you catch a glimpse of naked skin
2. Don't get excited every time you catch a glimpse of the naked skin
3. Don't get excited every time you catch a glimpse of a naked skin

Which sentence is correct? Or are all three of them wrong?

Comment: Hello Uriel! Welcome to [ell.se]. When you have a moment, please take our [tour] and read through our [help] to learn more about us. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#1 is the most natural sentence and would be the most common to hear. It would be appropriate when referring to the human body, whether seen personally or photographically.

The other examples would be inappropriate when referring to humans. Or, perhaps more accurately, it would be the stuff of a horror movie to use them in reference to a human. In the correct context, #2 would make sense referring to a single tanned hide or an artistic creation of taxidermy. #3 would make sense referring to the possibility of seeing any tanned hide or creations of taxidermy.